# have too many methods in view controller but don't know what other classes to create or which methods to move there

Tags: cocoa-touch, model-view-controller

I'm a newbie working on an app that both shows the user haiku chosen at random from a collection that comes with the app and allows him/her to write haiku to add that collection.  It also takes the user to a webview of a page from which s/he can buy haiku books.  The thing is, I've put almost all my methods in the view controller, and I have a feeling that good MVC work would divide this up differently.  Here are my basic methods (I've merged a few, left a few out that are submethods of other methods, and also Foundation and UIKit methods, for the sake of brevity), with brief descriptions:

```
GHHaiku.m //This is a model class, or at least I think it is.

-(int)chooseNumber {
returns a random number 
}

-(NSString *)haikuToShow {
uses that number to return haiku from collection
}

GHViewController.m

-(void) viewDidLoad
-(void) viewDidUnload

-(void) clearScreen {
gets rid of all UITextFields and images so that a new set of them can be created, perhaps with different parameters.
}

-(void) saveData {
saves persistent information like whether user has read the instructions
}

-(void)home {
takes user “home” from whatever screen we're in and shows next haiku
}

//--code to set up navBar and Toolbar

-(void)createNavBar:title {
creates and adds buttons to a UINavigationItem with “title” as title and adds UINavigationBar to view
}

-(void) loadToolbar {
loads toolbar at bottom of screen and adds buttons
}

//--code for instructions page

-(void) haikuInstructions {
shows instructions on screen
}

//--code for Amazon page

-(void) loadAmazon {
loads webview of haiku page at amazon.com
}

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView)
-(BOOL) webview:(UIWebView) shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest) navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)
-(void) connectWithURL☹NSString) andBaseURLString: (NSString)
-(BOOL) connection: (NSURLConnection) didFailWithError: (NSError)

-(void) doneWithAmazon {
takes user out of webview Amazon and shows next haiku
}

//--code for compose page

-(void) createSpaceToWrite {
sets up and shows an editable UITextView
}

-(void) userWritesHaiku {
allows user to write haiku
}

-(void) userEditsHaiku {
takes user to edit screen for haiku s/he’s already written.

-(void) userFinishedWritingHaiku {
shows action sheet once user’s done
}

-(void) deleteHaiku {
allows user to delete haiku s/he’s written
}

-(void) saveUserHaiku {
saves user haiku to documents folder
}

-(void) takeToOptOut {
allows user to opt out of sending haiku to central database
}

//--code for sharing

-(void) createImage {
creates image of haiku
}

-(void) showActionSheet {
gives user options to tweet, faceBook, or email
}

-(void) share {
allows user to tweet, email, or facebook that image
}

//--code for display page

-(IBAction)chooseDatabase: (UISegmentedControl) {
allows user to choose whether to see his/her own haiku and/or haiku that come with the application
}

-(void) fadeView {
fades the UISegmentedControl for chooseDatabase
}

-(void) nextHaiku {
shows next haiku
}

-(void) previousHaiku {
shows previous haiku
}
```

I have to imagine that some of those belong in separate classes, but I don't know what to put where and what to keep in GHViewController.  (I think part of my confusion comes because "view controller" has both "view" and "controller" in it and I don't understand whether it's a view, a controller, or neither....)

Anyway, I would love suggestions about other classes I ought to create and which methods I should put in them.

Comment: Ah, there's no such thing as "too many methods in a view controller".  The more the merrier.  (Seriously, your list doesn't seem particularly odd.  You do want to break out code that doesn't need to access the data or methods of the class under consideration (whether VC or not), but despite some claims to the contrary there are no really good rules you can come up with for when to do this -- In some cases it's glaringly obvious but other cases are a real judgment call.)

Comment: It's a controller.  :-)  Without trying to get into specifics, it's very common in iOS apps to put too much of the model into controllers.  I do it rather frequently...then go back, create objects that are responsible for managing my model, and move controller methods into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of those methods are appropriate for a view controller (anything where something is "shown" or doing something with views).  You might want to extract the logic for managing the haikus though... like the saveUserHaiku: and deleteHaiku: methods should at at least call into a model.  The model then might post a notification or callback a delegate to notify of changed data... your view controller being that delegate or observer, and it would respond appropriately to the now deleted haiku, or saved haiku if there is visible change.

The methods nextHaiku and previousHaiku make sense in the view controller, but again, should call to a model object to actually retrieve data.

The model should be keeping track of what database it's using, so while code to allow the user to choose the database resides in the view controller, the available databases and selected database comes from the model.

Also, your code to share things can be divided as well.  Code that displays visual elements and controls should be in the view controller, but you might have a share utility object that knows how to package up the data and send it off to the appropriate place.